# How to test member-wise equality operator?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, testing, c++20

I have a structure of three members `{ xx, xy, yy }` and an overloaded `==` operator that member-wise tests if corresponding members of left-hand and right-hand expressions are either equal within some precision, or are both `NaN`s. Quite trivial.

For my test case, I wanted to target a typo situation, where I mistakingly compare wrong members. Maybe, I compare `xx` from left-hand expression with `xy` from right-hand expression. Maybe, I forgot to compare `yy` at all.

Since I'm using C++20, I don't know if it's even possible to construct a compile-time proof of correctness of `==` operator (and if I even should). Trying to solve this in usual manner, I find myself enumerating all possible permutations:

```
EXPECT_EQ(C{1, 2, 3}, C{1, 2, 3});
EXPECT_NE(C{1, 2, 3}, C{1, 3, 2});
EXPECT_NE(C{1, 2, 3}, C{2, 1, 3});
EXPECT_NE(C{1, 2, 3}, C{2, 3, 1});
EXPECT_NE(C{1, 2, 3}, C{3, 1, 2});
EXPECT_NE(C{1, 2, 3}, C{3, 2, 1});
EXPECT_NE(C{1, 2, 3}, C{1, 2, nan});
EXPECT_NE(C{1, 2, 3}, C{1, nan, 3});
EXPECT_NE(C{1, 2, 3}, C{nan, 2, 3});
// ...

EXPECT_NE(C{1, 3, 2}, C{1, 2, 3});
EXPECT_EQ(C{1, 3, 2}, C{1, 3, 2});
// ...
```

Such code is quite ugly, and if I replicate the same with nested loops:

```
for (T lxx = 1; lxx <= 3; lxx += 1) {
  for (T rxx = 1; rxx <= 3; rxx += 1) {
    for (T lxy = 1; lxy <= 3; lxy += 1) {
      for (T rxy = 1; rxy <= 3; rxy += 1) {
        // ...
```

it just seems that I am reimplementing equality operator in test, which misses the point of testing.

How do I do this correctly? Am I missing some edge cases maybe that would simplify it? How to scale such test if I have four members in a structure and don't want for test case code to explode?

Comment: There's no way to *prove* the correctness of your function, unless you check all possible inputs.

Comment: @cigien I agree for the tests. But otherwise it is possible to proof code correctness without test using curry-howard isomorphism and a proof assistant (Coq).

Comment: There is always a point in tests, where human validation is necessary. As many test often depends of the validity of the equality operator, this equality operator end-up in not being testable using usual behavioral test technics. It is not a bad idea to write or copy paste the body of the equality operator inside the test, check it twice, look at the input. At least your test will catch regressions.

Answer (score 0):

Unit-testing is not about having proof of correctness, it's about having confidence in the code's behavior.

Let's say your operator is defined like this:

```
bool operator==(T const& lhs, T const& rhs) {
    return (lhs.xx - rhs.xx) <= epsilon && (lhs.xy - rhs.xy) <= epsilon && (lhs.yy - rhs.yy) <= epsilon;
}
```

There is no point in testing as many inputs as you can. The function is quite trivial, and you should focus on what could go wrong.

For example, you say you want to make sure there is no typo that could make the function compare the wrong members. Well, a test of equality like the first one you wrote, `EXPECT_EQ(C{1, 2, 3}, C{1, 2, 3})`, is all you need. If each member has a value different from each other by at least epsilon, then there is little chance for the test to pass while your function is comparing the wrong members.

By the way, you mention your equality operator checks if corresponding members are either within some precision or both NaNs. I don't think you want NaNs to compare equal. By definition, they aren't numbers, so equality is not defined for them. That's why IEEE 754 NaNs never compare equal, even when their binary representation is identical.

If you don't, then testing with NaNs is kind of useless here, since NaNs propagate and, again, don't compare to anything. If you do, then you wrote some special case for them which you want to test, but one or two equality tests are sufficient for that.

Something you might want to check is whether the epsilon (if that's what you actually use) has a reasonable value in different situations. That also comes with the matter of transitivity (or lack thereof), but that's a behavior that you must decide on.